Lightning datatable display data from apex controller
I am testing lightning datatable with a simple controller.
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static CustomObject__c getMyCustomObject(String contactId){
    try {
        system.debug('contactid:' + contactId);
        // check if the contact id is null or empty string then return null
        if(String.isBlank(contactId)){
            return null;
        }
        List<CustomObject__c> objects = [SELECT Id, Name
                                         FROM CustomObject__c WHERE Contact__c =: contactId];
        
        return objects[0];  // there will be only one records against a contact
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}

JS Controller
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getCustomObjData from '@salesforce/apex/SalesHubUserManagementController.getMyCustomObject';

export default class someClass extends LightningElement {
    customData = []
    customColumns = [];
    @api
    get labels() {
        return this._labels;
    }

    set labels(value) {
        if (value) {
           this._labels = value;
           this.initColumns();
        }
     }

@wire(getCustomObjData, {contactId: '$contactId'})
wiredData({ error, data }) {
    console.log('contactid:', this.contactId);
    if (data) {
        console.log('data:', data);
        this.customData= data;
        this.error = undefined;
    } 
    console.log(' data:', JSON.stringify(this.customData));
    
}

initColumns() {
    this.customColumns= [
        { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text' },
    ];
}

HTML
<template>
    <lightning-datatable
                key-field="Id"
                data={customData}
                columns={customColumns}>
    </lightning-datatable>
    
</template>

In the console I can the data coming but it is not mapping to the data-table.

You have not called the initColumns method in JS to initialize the columns.

@TusharJadav - sorry I was looking for a minimal code, that's it was truncated. The point is that I am getting the columns generated as well. It is just the data that's not being mapped.

Data tables require an Array to display data. As such, your data needs to be an Array.
Consider just returning a List of records, like this:
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static CustomObject__c[] getMyCustomObject(String contactId){
    return [SELECT Id, Name FROM CustomObject__c WHERE Contact__c = :contactId];
}

Alternatively, you could make the Array on the client, like this:
this.customerData = [data];

Either way, if there's only ever going to be a single entry, I'd suggest that this probably isn't the most elegant UI design, as data tables aren't great in the mobile experience.
